# I have trouble scheduling an AWS Batch Job

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-event-bridge, aws-batch

I am trying to schedule an AWS Batch Job using the AWS EventBridge. I try to create a schedule but then it gives me an error Invalid RequestJson provided. Reason Request payload is missing the following field(s): JobName, JobQueue, JobDefinition.

I selected AWS Batch as a target API when creating a schedule and in it, I also chose the AWS Batch Submit Job option.

This is the JSON input I wrote in the same Select Target Section in the Submit Job JSON input field.

```
{
  "jobName": "insiderTradersJob556",
  "jobDefinition": "arn:aws:batch:us-east-2:157733351594:job-definition/insiderTraders:1",
  "jobQueue": "arn:aws:batch:us-east-2:157733351594:job-queue/insider-traders-script",
  "dependsOn": [],
  "arrayProperties": {},
  "retryStrategy": {},
  "timeout": {},
  "parameters": {},
  "containerOverrides": {
    "command": [
      "python",
      "insiderTradersUploader.py"
    ],
    "resourceRequirements": [],
    "environment": []
  }
}
```

When submitting a job through AWS Batch using this same JSON input, it works perfectly fine. The job succeeded and it worked as expected.

My execution role is Amazon_EventBridge_Scheduler_ECS_4347190648

I tried using

```
{
  "jobName": "insiderTradersJob556",
  "jobDefinition": "arn:aws:batch:us-east-2:157733351594:job-definition/insiderTraders:1",
  "jobQueue": "arn:aws:batch:us-east-2:157733351594:job-queue/insider-traders-script"
}
```

but it still didn't work.

I also tried using the AWS lambda functions. I tried creating a function with the container image i used in the AWS Batch (the image is saved in the Elastic Container Registry).However, it just said the image is not found :(

My execution role has multiple permissions. First one is:

```
    {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": [
                    "batch:SubmitJob",
                    "batch:DescribeJobQueues"
                ],
                "Resource": "arn:aws:batch:us-east-2:157733351594:job-queue/insider-traders-script"
            }
        ]
    }
```

My second one is

```
    {
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Action": [
                    "batch:SubmitJob"
                ],
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Resource": [
                    "arn:aws:batch:us-east-2:157733351594:job-definition/getting-started-wizard-job-definition:1",
                    "arn:aws:batch:us-east-2:157733351594:job-queue/insider-traders-script"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "Version": "2012-10-17"
    }
```

My other ones are AmazonRDSFullAccess, AWSBatchServiceRole and AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy. I am suspecting I need some other role.

Answer (score 1):

The request object parameters should be start with capital letters as below

```json
{
  "JobName": "insiderTradersJob556",
  "JobDefinition": "arn:aws:batch:us-east-2:157733351594:job-definition/insiderTraders:1",
  "JobQueue": "arn:aws:batch:us-east-2:157733351594:job-queue/insider-traders-script"
}
```